# how can i increase my enemy position every second in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I created a tilebased game, where the enemy tries to chase the player, but after using the pathfinding program, I have determined every position the enemy has to move in order to reach the player, but i want the enemy every half a second that passes by to go to the next position on my list, here is my code:

```
self.grid = grid
        self.end = grid.node(player_x // tile_size,player_y // tile_size)
        
        path,runs = finder.find_path(self.start,self.end,self.grid)
        if len(self.pathway_x) < len(path):
            for x in path:
                self.pathway_x.append(x[0])
                self.pathway_y.append(x[1])
        if clock.get_fps() != 0:
            self.timer += int(1 / clock.get_fps())
        for i in range(len(self.pathway_x)):
            if self.timer == 0:
                self.x = self.pathway_x[i] * tile_size
                self.y = self.pathway_y[i] * tile_size
```

Let me further explain,
I have a list:

`positions = [[100,100],[150,100],[150,150]]`

and i have an enemy, that every one second i want it to go from its position to the first position on this list above, so lets just say the enemy position is `(50,50)` i want it to move from `(50,50)` to `100,100`, but how do i do so, i have a timer, but how can i detect if it incremented by 1 every time. Cause i dont want to detect if it is one, cause if i do then it will keep switching positions every frame.

Hope this clears out everything.

Answer (score 0):

In pygame exists a timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. The time has to be set in milliseconds. For a timer event you need to define a unique user events id. The ids for the user events have to be between `pygame.USEREVENT` (24) and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (32). In the following the event is 24 (`pygame.USEREVENT`):

```py
enemy_interval = 1000 # 1 seconds
enemy_event_id = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(enemy_event_id, enemy_interval)

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

         elif event.type == enemy_event_id:

             # move the enemies forward 1 step
             # [...]
```

---

Store the current index of the position in the list and change the index when the timer event occurs:

```py
pos_index = (pos_index + 1) % len(corner_points)
x, y = corner_points[pos_index]
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

corner_points = [(50, 50), (150, 50), (150, 150), (100, 100), (50, 150)]
x, y = corner_points[0]
pos_index = 0

enemy_interval = 1000
enemy_event_id = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(enemy_event_id, enemy_interval)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == enemy_event_id:
            pos_index = (pos_index + 1) % len(corner_points)
            x, y = corner_points[pos_index]
           
    screen.fill(0) 
    pygame.draw.lines(screen, "white", True, corner_points)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, "red", (x, y), 10)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```